# ElasticSearch installation error with CLASSPATH

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting the below mentioned error when i am trying to install elastic search version 6.6.0 on my windows 10 OS. The command i am using to install is

-- Command:
elasticsearch -Ecluster.name=TestES -Enode.name=First_Node

-- Error:
\Java\jre-9.0.4\bin\java.exe" -cp "!ES_CLASSPATH!" "org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.TempDirectory""` was unexpected at this time.

-- Java Version install on my pc:
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)

Please guide how to fix this issue.

Regards
Qasim

Comment: I can't help with this installation problem, but I would advise to look into Docker which you can use to run lots of different software, ElasticSearch included. There's some learning curve, but it bring a lot of benefits and running ES locally will be as easy as running `docker run elasticsearch`. You can download Docker here: https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows . Let me know if you have further questions regarding using Docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same issue i was getting on my machine.

I then found issue was related to 32 bit Java was installed instead of 64 bit, i [reinstalled](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

if your java is installed under C:\Program Files (x86) then set the JAVA_HOME like will below

set JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~2\Java\jre1.8.0_131

if your java is installed under C:\Program Files then set the JAVA_HOME like will below
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jre1.8.0_131

After that try to start the elastic search, it should start then.

Thanks & Regards
Jaiswar Vipin Kumar R.